# Removing Child In XML Via PowerShell?

Tags: .net, xml, powershell

I've Searched all the place to find an answer to this, but I can't seem to find one that works for me and yes I am aware that this has been asked a lot but none work.

This is my code:

```
$Request = Invoke-RestMethod ($BaseURL + $StatPage) -WebSession  $Session -Method Post -Body $StatBody
$Request = $Request | Where-Object {$_.'mac' -ne "00:00:00:00:00:00"}
```

Instead of removing the node it just prints it out, I've even tried:

```
foreach($Node in $Request.'ajax-response'.response.'acl-list'.acl.deny)
{
     if($Node.'mac' -eq "00:00:00:00:00:00")
     {
         $Node.ParentNode.RemoveNode($Node)
     }
}
```

Which yields the good old error: `Collection was of a fixed size.`.

I've tried a few others but no longer have the code, the MAC is valid and is in the list and have validated this via saving it and checking.

Here is some example [XML](https://pastebin.com/r5RLanBu)

I need to use XML as the API only supports that, I've really hit a brick wall and would like some help :)

Comment: What is the type of `$Request` . `$Request.GetType()` ?

Comment: Seems strange that first you filter `$Request` to NOT have elements `.mac` that have a value of `"00:00:00:00:00:00"` and then later on you loop through the request to find an remove exactly those elements (that are not present in the $Request because you have filtered them out..)

Comment: The document type is Xml Document and I don't control this api and need to keep the structure of the document and can't just take out the mac array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the error `Collection was of a fixed size.` suggests you may be working with collections\arrays instead of an XML Element.

You could explicitly cast the `Invoke-RestMethod` output to an XmlDocument:

```
[xml] $Request = Invoke-RestMethod ($BaseURL + $StatPage) -WebSession  $Session -Method Post -Body $StatBody
```

And calling the method `RemoveChild()` on the nodes you want to remove:

```
foreach($Node in $Request.'ajax-response'.response.'acl-list'.acl.deny)
{
     if($Node.'mac' -eq "00:00:00:00:00:00")
     {
         $Node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($Node)
     }
}
```

If you are not interested in the output that `RemoveChild()` gives, you can pipe it to null:

```
$Node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($Node) | Out-Null
```

Comment: This works maginally, however when I output the $Request after the RemoveChild it keeps the supposedly removed element.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it after calling .Save("") to save to a file, ideally I'd like to do this without having to save to a file, but I guess this works well enough :).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you but here's what I did. I used data from your link:

```
<ajax-request action="updobj" comp="acl-list" updater="blocked-clients">
    <acl id="1" name="System" description="System" default-mode="allow" EDITABLE="false">
        <deny type="single" mac="c0:bd:d1:14:62:68"/>
        <deny mac="c0:d3:c0:1c:60:93" type="single"/>
        <deny type="single" mac="b4:74:43:c0:f3:cf"/>
        <deny type="single" mac="c0:ee:fb:25:ca:7c"/>
        <deny type="single" mac="48:db:50:ed:71:36"/>
        <deny mac="d4:50:3f:fd:48:2f" type="single"/>
        <deny type="single" mac="58:48:22:c2:44:2e"/>
    </acl>
</ajax-request>
```

Then I did the following, just loop through the data and create the new file without the unwanted mac:

```
 [xml]$xml = Get-Content "C:\Users\b.moeskops\Desktop\test.xml"
    $data = $xml.'ajax-request'.acl.deny
    $wrongData = "c0:d3:c0:1c:60:93"

    foreach($Node in $data){
        if($Node.'mac' -eq $wrongData){
            $data = $data | Where-Object {$_.mac -ne $wrongData} 
        }
    }
    $data
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It does! However I need to keep the rest of the xml document intact and not create just a new list

Comment: Do you have any other ideas for me short of doing it this way then just converting to string and padding the rest of the XML around it?

Answer (score 0):

I might have found something that works...
I used the data from your link again.

```
$Path = "H:\test.xml"
$xml = Get-Content $Path

$array = $xml | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach($obj in $array.value){
    if($obj -match '<deny type="single" mac="c0:bd:d1:14:62:68"/>' -or $obj -match '<deny mac="c0:d3:c0:1c:60:93" type="single"/>'){
        $array2 = $array.value | Where-Object {$_ -ne $obj}
    }
}
$array2
```

First the file:

```
 <ajax-request action="updobj" comp="acl-list" updater="blocked-clients">
    <acl id="1" name="System" description="System" default-mode="allow" EDITABLE="false">
        <deny type="single" mac="c0:bd:d1:14:62:68"/>
        <deny mac="c0:d3:c0:1c:60:93" type="single"/>
        <deny type="single" mac="b4:74:43:c0:f3:cf"/>
        <deny type="single" mac="c0:ee:fb:25:ca:7c"/>
        <deny type="single" mac="48:db:50:ed:71:36"/>
        <deny mac="d4:50:3f:fd:48:2f" type="single"/>
        <deny type="single" mac="58:48:22:c2:44:2e"/>
    </acl>
</ajax-request>
```

This file is saved at 'H:\test.xml'. After running the script the output for $array2 is:

```
$array2
<ajax-request action="updobj" comp="acl-list" updater="blocked-clients">
    <acl id="1" name="System" description="System" default-mode="allow" EDITABLE="false">
        <deny type="single" mac="c0:bd:d1:14:62:68"/>
        <deny type="single" mac="b4:74:43:c0:f3:cf"/>
        <deny type="single" mac="c0:ee:fb:25:ca:7c"/>
        <deny type="single" mac="48:db:50:ed:71:36"/>
        <deny mac="d4:50:3f:fd:48:2f" type="single"/>
        <deny type="single" mac="58:48:22:c2:44:2e"/>
    </acl>
</ajax-request>
```

If you examine the file, you can see that I have removed the content from the file and kept the format intact.

As you can see I removed two lines of the XML file, I did this because there are 2 different formats found inside the file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This isn't as simple as it looks after all, the results of GetType() on the variable holding my XML is XmlDocument, but when I run this code I don't get any output, nor do I get any returned list it seems my powershell wants to make this impossible for me :(